# Refactor multiple if if/else if with null checks more elegantly

Tags: java, java-8, refactoring

I have a multiple if else if which does a null check inside a try/catch block. I know there is a better way to refactor it but at loss here considering i am a newbie to java 8 (bit embarrassing really).

My if else block

I had tried using Optional.ofNullable but with no vail

```
try {
                if (this.oldInvestigator != null) {
                    if (this.oldInvestigator.getId() == null && this.newInvestigator.getId() != null) {
                        someService.sendEmailToInvestigator(newInvestigator);

                    } else if (this.oldInvestigator.getId() != null && this.newInvestigator.getId() != null) {
                        someService.updateInvestigator(this.oldInvestigator, this.newInvestigator);

                    } else {
                        someService.sendNotificationToLeader();
                    }
                }
}
```

There are more conditions similar to this in my java class file (courtesy of my predecessors). I want to refactor them in the best way possible either using java 8 or by using a common design implementation

Comment: You should rethink your habit of using `null` excessively. But here you go: `if(newInvestigator.getId() == null) someService.sendNotificationToLeader(); else if(oldInvestigator.getId() == null) someService.sendEmailToInvestigator(newInvestigator); else someService.updateInvestigator(oldInvestigator, newInvestigator);`, the whole thing still wrapped in an `if(oldInvestigator != null)) { … }`

Answer (score 1):

You can make it a bit more readable by inverting the null checks and returning immediately.

```
try {
    if (this.oldInvestigator == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (this.oldInvestigator.getId() == null && this.newInvestigator.getId() != null) {
        someService.sendEmailToInvestigator(newInvestigator);

    } else if (this.oldInvestigator.getId() != null && this.newInvestigator.getId() != null) {
        someService.updateInvestigator(this.oldInvestigator, this.newInvestigator);

    } else {
        someService.sendNotificationToLeader();
    }
}
```

However, this isn't really the issue.  The problem is that you need to rethink your approach.  It's not ideal to use null checks to determine a particular path in your code.  Ask yourself why oldInvestigator.getId() should ever return null in the first place.  Should you mandate instead that you provide an Id when you create the oldInvestigator object?  Try to have a think about how you can change the fundamental design instead of trying to see how you can make it look nicer when checking the values.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this would be better.
In sample code here, both OldInvestigator and NewInvestigator refer to same class;

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.util.Optional;


    public class OldInvestigator
    {

        //id is optional
        private Optional<String> id;

        public Optional<String> getId()
        {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(String id)
        {
            this.id = Optional.of(id);
        }

    }
```

Now can define in helper class or another service ( ensure reusability ) a logic like this ( below is for reference only, rename, move & tweak based on your business logic )

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.util.Optional;

public class Processor
{

    private static Optional<OldInvestigator> oldInvestigatorOpt = null;

    private static Optional<OldInvestigator> newInvestigatorOpt = null;

    //enum identifying who was available
    private enum InvestigatorPresence
    {
        OLD,
        NEW,
        BOTH,
        NONE
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        switch (getInvestigatorPresence(oldInvestigatorOpt, newInvestigatorOpt)) {
            case BOTH:
                // someService.updateInvestigator(oldInvestigatorOpt.get(), newInvestigatorOpt.get())
                break;
            case NEW:
                // someService.sendEmailToInvestigator(newInvestigatorOpt.get());
                break;
            case OLD:
                // someService.sendNotificationToLeader();
                break;
            case NONE:
                // handle
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    private static InvestigatorPresence getInvestigatorPresence(Optional<OldInvestigator> oldInvestigatorOpt,
        Optional<OldInvestigator> newInvestigatorOpt)
    {
        boolean isOldPresent = oldInvestigatorOpt.isPresent() && oldInvestigatorOpt.get().getId().isPresent();
        boolean isNewPresent = newInvestigatorOpt.isPresent() && newInvestigatorOpt.get().getId().isPresent();

        if (isOldPresent) {
            if (isNewPresent) {
                return InvestigatorPresence.BOTH;
            } else {
                return InvestigatorPresence.OLD;
            }
        } else if (isNewPresent) {
            return InvestigatorPresence.NEW;
        } else {
            return InvestigatorPresence.NONE;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can have a action class which checks a condition then calls your service or delegates to next action, like

```
new Action<>(oldInvestigator, newInvestigator)
  .orExecute((o, n) -> o.getId() == null && n.getId() != null, (o, n) -> someService.sendEmailToInvestigator(n))
  .orExecute((o, n) -> o.getId() != null && n.getId() != null, someService::updateInvestigator)
  .orExecute((o, n) -> true,                                   (o, n) -> someService.sendNotificationToLeader());
```

and here's how `Action` looks like:

```
class Action<T1, T2> {
    private T1 o1;
    private T2 o2;
    private boolean done;

    //all args private constructor
    //two args public constructor    

    Action<T1, T2> orExecute(BiPredicate<T1, T2> biPredicate, CheckedBiConsumer<T1, T2> biConsumer) throws Exception {
        if(!done && biPredicate.test(o1, o2)) {
            biConsumer.accept(o1, o2);
            return new Action<>(o1, o2, true);
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For null check only you could consider following better way.

```
Objects.isNull(Object obj)
```

and

```
Objects.nonNull(Object obj)
```

of course few versions of

```
Objects.requireNonNull()
```